# CakePHP 1.3: Server power outage. Now plugin wont work

Tags: cakephp

My host had a power outage on their servers which caused a lot of headaches, including some corrupted database tables. All that seems to be fixed now. However, I am having issues connecting to my plugins.

When I try I get the following error:

```
 Error: The requested address '/admin/paginas/paginas' was not found on this server.
```

All the other plugins are displaying the similar errors.

I have uploaded the entire cake library thinking it is a corrupted file there. However it does not work. I have also uploaded routes.php.

Where should I look to fix this problem?

Comment: Start by setting `debug` to `2`: `Configure::write('debug', 2)`

Comment: I tried that and it points out that `tmp/cache` is not writable. I have made these folders 777 many times and Cake still tells me it is not writable.

Comment: FIXED. I am not sure why, but after my Host recovered files from the OUTAGE `CACHE` ended up in `/tmp/logs/cache`. I moved it to `/tmp/cache` and everything now works. RATHER STRANGE

Comment: A power outage changed code? Skynet is real! Run!

Comment: At first I thought it corrupted code. However, somehow (???), the CACHE folder was placed at the wrong location. PROBLEM FIXED!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED. I am not sure why, but after my Host recovered files from the OUTAGE `CACHE` ended up in `/tmp/logs/`. I moved it to `/tmp/`and everything now works. RATHER STRANGE